# Loading fsx files dynamically in an FSX script

Tags: scripting, f#, f#-fake

We are sharing a build script for FAKE across a set of projects. We want to keep this one build script the same but make it possible to extend with other targets. One way I could think of doing this is by loading `.fsx` files if they fit a specific naming pattern like al files that matches `build-*.fsx` however I can't seem to think of a way to load these files dynamically. Any suggestions on how to do this or how to accomplish the desired result are all good as answers

if I could I would have done something like

```
#load "build-*.fsx"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me why you want to do this but maybe this will help. Refer to a single script in each project:

```ml
#load "load-build-scripts.fsx"
```

And then in single `load-build-scripts.fsx`:

```ml
#load "build-1.fsx"
#load "build-2.fsx"
#load "build-3.fsx"
...
```

This second file you will need to change whenever you add a new script.

---

It's not generally recommended to do this. Because now if these separate scripts refer to each other then some scripts will be loaded more than once. Scripts aren't really meant to be used for cases this complex.

Another option is to use FAKE as a console project instead of using scripts and the fake-cli tool. Then you can use normal .NET project dependencies.

Comment: Yes that would work but would require an empty file to be present (if there are no extensions to the build te no extra scripts to be loaded). I would like to avoid having this empty file, thus loading the script files only if they are present